# How to relatively change size of seaborn plot?

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

I know how to set size in inches:

```
sns.histplot(df['A'], bins=50, kde=True, color='blue');
fig = plt.gcf()
fig.set_size_inches( 2, 2)
```

I want to make the histogram smaller, but if I go too small some part of it can be cut.

Is there a simple way to just set the percentage of the picture you want?

Comment: It's a bit unclear what you mean by *"set the percentage of the picture you want"*. But you can set some figure size, and afterwards call `fig.tight_layout()` to make labels and ticks fit nicely. This gives a warning when the size is too small to fit everything.

Comment: I want the same ratio between all the elements in the figure, just reduce the overall size proportionally.

Comment: thanks, it helps, but still need to work on it.

Comment: fig_ratio = fig.bbox_inches.max[0] / fig.bbox_inches.max[1]
        fig.set_size_inches(fig_ratio * 3, 3). I tried this to check the original size and change it accordingly.